# Zend Encrypt and Decrypt

Tags: php, security, encryption, zend-framework, cryptography

I have the below class:

```php
<?php

class Application_Model_Classes_Cryptography
{
    private static $key  = "thisisakeytolock";
    private static $vector= "myvector";

    public static function encrypt($data)
    {
        $filter = new Zend_Filter_Encrypt(array('adapter' => 'mcrypt', 'key' => Application_Model_Classes_Cryptography::$key));
        $filter->setVector(Application_Model_Classes_Cryptography::$vector);
        $encrypted = $filter->filter($data);
        return utf8_encode(base64_encode($encrypted));
    }

    public static function decrypt($data)
    {
        $filter = new Zend_Filter_Decrypt(array('adapter' => 'mcrypt', 'key' => Application_Model_Classes_Cryptography::$key));
        $filter->setVector(Application_Model_Classes_Cryptography::$vector);
        $decrypted = $filter->filter(base64_decode(utf8_decode($data)));
        return $decrypted;
    }
}
```

but when I use those methods though the result seems correct but does't work

```php
$varData = 'someinformation';
$conData = Application_Model_Classes_Cryptography::decrypt(Application_Model_Classes_Cryptography::encrypt($varData));

echo $varData;
echo $conData;

if($varData == $conData) echo "equal";
else echo "not equal";
```

here is the result:

```php
someinformation
someinformation
not equal
```

can anyone please help me in understanding what's wrong here.

basically I want to send some encrypted information and once receive in the other server want to decrypt and extract that information. but the problem is that the the information seems to be the same but doesn't compare. I have tried adding the utf8_encode and decode in the methods as you can see in there, but no gain.

**System Details:**
**OS:** Mac OS X 10.11
**MAMP:** 3.5
**PHP:** 5.6.10

Comment: Why are you using `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()`? Mcrypt adds `NUL` bytes at the end of your encrypted message. Use OpenSSL instead. [Never use mcrypt](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).

Comment: @ScottArciszewski thanks ... I was not aware of that padding thing. I tried utf8 encode decode to see if that was an encoding issue. But now I am using trim and replacing the "\x0" char from the decoded string, which is making it work fine.

Comment: Okay, try encrypting a string that ends in "\x00" (e.g. a raw hash) with mcrypt, then decrypt it. Do you get the same string afterwards? **The problem is using mcrypt at all; don't use mcrypt!**

Comment: @ScottArciszewski got it ... thanks